# Working with Eigen::TensorBase as function argument fails

Tags: c++, eigen3

The following is a minimal example what I try to achieve:

```
  //*** This is in one lib.

  // Generic data processing function.
  template<typename T>
  bool process_data(const T* ptr, size_t N)
  {
    // Whatever.
    return false;
  }

  // Interface to data processing function for Tensor (agnostic for rank...).
  template<typename T>
  bool process_tensor(const Eigen::TensorBase<T, Eigen::ReadOnlyAccessors>& tensor)
  {
  //  return process_data(tensor.???, tensor.???);     // PROBLEM 1
  }

  // Function pointer to data processing function for Tensor.
  bool (*process_tensor_ptr_float)(const Eigen::TensorBase<float, Eigen::ReadOnlyAccessors>& tensor) = process_tensor<float>;

  //*** The function pointer is made available to another lib as an
  // 'extern' global variable (a bit dirty, yes...).

  // Test the function pointer.
  void test()
  {
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> tensor(2, 3, 4);
 //   process_tensor_ptr_float(tensor);     // PROBLEM 2
  }
```

Having the function pointer is crucial for me, because it is used to share between libraries.

Basically I have 2 problems I cannot solve:

1. Problem 1: I have no idea how to access the underlying data to get a
   pointer to the data and its size. Class methods for doing that do
   not seem to be available, maybe something with `derived()`, but
   TensorBase is completely undocumented... I tried some things like
   `derived().data()` but all I get is a list of compiler errors.
2. Problem 2: The function `process_tensor()` does not accept the tensor:
   `invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Eigen::TensorBase<float, 0>&' from expression of type 'Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>`, plus a large list of errors
   `invalid use of incomplete type ...`.

If I cannot get this to work, the only option I see is that I make a function pointer directly to `process_data()`, and then the caller must do some extra work to get a correct call for different datatypes like `Eigen::Matrix`, `Eigen::Tensor` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from really wanting to know the answer to the original question, I solved things a bit different now. Earlier I had specific pointers that already pointed to wrapper functions which had TensorBase as an argument. Now I see I can interchange the order of function pointer (now points to the raw data processor function and becomes available in other libs) and wrappers:

```
 // Generic data processing function.
 template<typename T>
 bool process_data(const T* ptr, size_t N)
 {
   // Whatever.
   return false;
 }

 // Function pointer to data processing function for Tensor.
 bool (*process_ptr_float)(const float* ptr, size_t N) = process_tensor<float>;

 // Interface to data processing function for Tensor.
 template<int _Rank>
 bool process_tensor_float(const Eigen::Tensor<float, _Rank>& values)
 {
     return process_ptr_float(tensor.data(), tensor.size());
 }

 // Test the wrapper function.
 void test()
 {
   Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> tensor(2, 3, 4);
   bool result = process_tensor_float(tensor);
 }
```

and `TensorBase` is not required anymore.